# offline kmz files

Tags: offline, kmz

What is the best way to create kmz files for offline use?

I need files that I can
put on a CD and a salesman can pull up all Google Earth data - map, placemarks, balloons, text and photos with no Internet connection.

Comment: Where are you getting your globe data for the offline connection?  Google Portable Earth Enterprise?

Answer (score 0):

You can have any level of nested KML or KMZ files within a KMZ file.
The KMZ file can display embedded images inline in popup balloons and link from one placemark to another. You can also display some content such as HTML files inline via an iframe in a balloon description.

Here is KML description snippet to display an inline image and external HTML (via iframe) from files embedded inside the KMZ file.

```
  <description>
 <![CDATA[
  Here is an image:<BR>
  <img src="image.gif"/>
  <BR>
  Here is html:
  <BR>
  <iframe src="test.html">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
  </iframe>
  ]]>
  </description>
```

Here are some restrictions for `<iframe>` content in the [KMZ Tutorial](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmzarchives)

> The `<src>` element within an `<iframe>` element cannot point to a local
>   file on disk, nor can it point to a file inside a KMZ file; it must
>   point to a URL on the Internet that a browser can visit.

If you want to link to non-KML documents (e.g. HTML, PDF, etc.) then embedding them inside a KMZ file has some further restrictions. Directly linking to local files (HTML, PDF, images, etc.) doesn't work from Google Earth if those files are inside the KMZ file.

If your target is an offline CD or DVD (no internet connection) then you can as easily create KML files with the media content in sub-folders (e.g. video, images, html, etc.). To link to non-KML files the user of that KML in Google Earth would need to enable the "*Allow access to local files and personal data*" option in Tools/Option/General menu panel then you'd be able to access those links as you would from a web browser.

The structure and layout of the CD/DVD and KML/KMZ files depends on several things: 1) the amount of data you want to make available and whether it fits on a CD or DVD in compressed or uncompressed form, and 2) whether you just want to display the content just within a KML description balloon or want to link to the content in a full-browser window. You may have a mix content -- some of which are to be displayed only inside the KML balloon descriptions in which case it could placed be inside a KMZ file if compression is needed and other content that needs to be linked and accessed externally.